# How redux form passing props from HOC to Input Element

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am using native-base (a material ui library for react-native) with redux form for managing state of form using redux. I am confused with the following bit of code. In below code it is taking number of argument and pass it to Input Tag with triple dot. but i could not identify what is this and from where it is getting rest of properties and how i can apply custom props.

```
renderInput({ input, label,  meta: { touched, error, warning } }){
    console.log(input)
    var hasError= false;
    if(error !== undefined){
      hasError= true;

    }
    return( 

      <Item error= {hasError}>
        <Input {...input} 
        />
        {hasError ? <Text>{error}</Text> : <Text />}
      </Item>
    )
  }
```

Below is the render method which is calling above function from Higher Order Field Component of redux form.

```
render(){
     const { handleSubmit, reset } = this.props;
     if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return <Expo.AppLoading />;
    }
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Body>
            <Title>Redux Form</Title>
          </Body>
        </Header>
        <Content padder>
          <Field name="email" component={this.renderInput} model="sudhakar" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
          <Field name="name" component={this.renderInput} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          <Input name="age" type="text" ref="_age" />
          <Button block primary onPress= {this.handleLogin}
            style={{marginHorizontal:10,backgroundColor:"#00adef", marginTop:50}}
          >
            <Text>Submit</Text>
          </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    )
  }
```

You can find complete code [here](http://docs.nativebase.io/docs/examples/ReduxFormExample.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to post comment because my reputation is below 50.

The triple dot is called [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), I think this is the key to understanding what you're confused about. when I first saw this syntax I had the same confusion. try reading the link above plus [this](https://davidwalsh.name/spread-operator) and I think you should be able to figure out ur problem :)

Comment: i also find the same answer but not able to understand from where does renderInput getting input parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure what `Field` is doing inside because I can't see what's inside `Field`, but I must assume when field takes `this.renderInput` as one of it's `props` called `component`, it is passing input parameter from inside `Field`, treating it much like a callback

Comment: i.e. inside field it may say something like `this.props.component(<whatever it wanna pass to renderInput as parameters>)`

Comment: i have found the answer by following a video tutorial.